# Question about labeling in Dijkstra's Proof of Correctness

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am trying to understand the proof of correctness for Dijkstra's algorithm (shown below) and also at the following link: [CS Auskland](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/dij-proof.html)

> Proof by contradiction
>
> Suppose that $u$ is the first vertex added to $S$ for which $d[u] \ne \delta(s,u)$. We note:
>
> $u$ cannot be $s$, because $d[s] = 0$.
>
> There must be a path from $s$ to $u$. If there were not, $d[u]$ would be infinity.
>
> Since there is a path, there must be a shortest path.
>
> When $x$ was inserted into $S$, $d[x] = \delta(s,x)$ (since we hypothesise that u was the first vertex for which this was not true).
>
> Edge $(x,y)$ was relaxed at that time, so that
>       $$d[y] = \delta(s,y)
> \le \delta(s,u)
> \le d[u]$$
>
> Now both $y$ and $u$ were in $V-S$ when u was chosen, so $d[u] \le d[y]$.

How can we say that $d[u] \le d[y]$?  And why aren't we saying that $d[u] \ge d[y]$?  Wouldn't the label on $u$ be larger if it is further down the path from $y$?

> Thus the two inequalities must be equalities,
>       $$d[y] = \delta(s,y) = \delta(s,u) = d[u]$$
>
> So $d[u] = \delta(s,u)$ contradicting our hypothesis.
>
> Thus when each $u$ was inserted, $d[u] = \delta(s,u)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the algorithm at each step adds to $S$ the vertex with the lowest "d" value, and $y$ is not in $S$, $d[u] \leq d[y]$.

Comment: So, since u was selected and y was not yet in S, we're assuming that d[u] is less than d[y]?  But since y is before u on the path from s to u, then d[y] <= d[u]; resulting in the contradiction?

Comment: Since u was selected and not y, d[y] cannot be greater than d[u], since if it were, the algorithm would choose y before u, but that cannot be the case since y is not in S. So since $d[u] \leq d[y]$, if you follow the inequalities on the description you linked to, you will end up deriving that $d[u] = \delta(s, u)$ contradicting the assumption that they are not equal.